# How to copy software DVD on another blank DVD

Tags: dvd, dvd-burning

How can I copy a Windows7 DVD to another DVD using a single DVD drive?

Comment: @chipperyman573: Not a duplicate of that one. You confused "copy a Windows 7 DVD" with "copy a DVD in Windows 7".

Comment: Could you please add more information? --- You would like to copy the installation DVD of Windows 7? In which operating system do you want to copy the DVD?

Answer (score 0):

You rip the first DVD to an ISO with a program like cdburnerxp.se

OR use one of these official copies from microsoft with SP1 built-in.

Windows 7 Home Premium x86  SP1 (bootable)
http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-24208.iso

Windows  7  Home Premium x64 SP1 (bootable)
http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-24209.iso

Windows 7 Professional x86 SP1 (bootable)
http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-24280.iso

Windows 7 Professional x64 SP1 (bootable)
http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-24281.iso

Windows 7 Ultimate x86 SP1 (bootable)
http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-24394.iso

Windows 7 Ultimate X64 SP1 (bootable)
http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-24395.iso